# How to force users to stay at new popup window for certain time?

Tags: javascript

I want to force users to stay at new tab for certain time befor they're allowed to close it.

here's an example: https://foom.egybest.co/ when users close popup window quickly it's block entire website and notify users to disable adblock.

```html
<img  onclick="xxx()" src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/1648/PNG/96/10094clownface_109962.png"  >


<script>
function xxx() {

var popUp = window.open('https://www.google.com/');

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(popUp.closed) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert('closed');
    }
}, 2000);

if (popUp == null || typeof(popUp)=='undefined') {  
    alert('AdBlock detect'); 
} 
else {  
    popUp.focus();
}
}


</script>
```

Comment: That is usually the moment when I block a website for good.

Comment: *Popupblocker* and *Addblocker* are different things. On many devices popups are blocked by default nowadays.

Comment: I try to build PTC website so this function allows users to collect reward if they stay at popup window for certain time @JavaScript

Comment: What is the issue with the code you provided?

Comment: My code don't do the trick, I want to use if(popUp.closed) befor 2sec show alert

Comment: Just lower the interval? Do you have control over all sites you open in the popup?

Comment: No I don't have accsess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had access to all links in question you could add a [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).

Else you have to split the duration logic from the checking logic. One version would be to set the interval low to check frequently and pass the starting time to the callback function, in which one can calculate the elapsed time.

Here is a short example:

```js
function xxx(link){
  var tObject = {
    popUp: window.open(link),
    startTime: Date.now(),
    requiredWaitingTimeInMS: 2000,
    Timer: null
  };

  //REM: No popup found
  if(!tObject.popUp){  
    alert('No popup detect')
  } 
  else{
    tObject.popUp.focus();
    tObject.Timer = setInterval(function(object){
      if(object){
        //REM: If there is no popup or the popup is closed, we are done
        if(!object.popUp || object.popUp.closed){
          //REM: Stopping timer and cleanup
          clearInterval(object.Timer);
          object = null;

          //REM: Output on fail
          alert('Not enough time')
        }
        //REM: Else if the popup is open and the waiting time passes 2000ms, we are done
        else if(
          Date.now() - object.startTime > object.requiredWaitingTimeInMS
        ){
          //REM: Stopping timer and cleanup
          clearInterval(object.Timer);
          object = null;

          //REM: Output on success
          alert('Enough time')
        }
      }
    }.bind(this, tObject), 50)
  }
}
```

```html
<img  onclick="xxx(this.src)" src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/1648/PNG/96/10094clownface_109962.png" >
```